# why geom_smooth not showing the smooth line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I am having a problem where geom_smooth() is not working on my ggplot2. 
But instead of a smooth curve, there is a fold.
[image]
My X-axis variable is the factor variable(I've tried to convert it to a numerical variable, but it didn't work), and Y-axis is numeric variable.
My data.frame is that [image] [image]

```
ggplot(tmp, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess", stat = "identity", se = T, group = "")
```

I hope to get a pic like this.
[image]

Comment: Delete `stat = "identity"` and `group = ""`

Comment: Tested deleting the `stat = "identity" ` and `group = " "`, and doing that alone isn't producing the desired output shown in the question. Just pointing that out, and that can be verified using a `df` with a similar structure as the question.

Comment: I have solved my problem by modifying the X-axis (1:n instead of the original factor coordinates).But thx all of U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix will be to wrap the group inside `aes`. Generated a data similar to the structure you have (a factor x variable and a numeric y var).

```r
set.seed(777)
x <- rep(c(LETTERS[1:7]), 3)
y <- rnorm(21, mean = 0, sd = 1)
tmp <- data.frame(x,y)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
base <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x = x, y = y))+geom_point()

base + geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess",se = TRUE, aes(group = "" ), level = 0.95) + theme_bw()
```

If you want to use a different level of confidence interval, you can change the value of level (which is a 95% by default).

## Output

[image: geom_smooth_output]

Comment: Thx, your answer helped me a lot!!

Comment: But I have a new question, why the line is not a smooth line but a fold line in your pic?

Comment: I seem to understand that if I want to get a smooth curve, my X-axis has to be a numerical variable rather than a factor coordinate.

Comment: If you want a straight line, change the method to `lm` which is a linear fitting than the `loess` which uses a different estimate for the fitting line (polynomial regression fitting).

Comment: @C.chen if you're satisfied with the answer, you might want to up-vote and mark it as an answer by clicking the right mark below the up-vote button.